Thermal resistance in heat transfer
Can a material experiencing heat generation be represented by thermal resistance and 
included in a circuit analysis? If so, why? If not, why not?
Consider a case with the solid cylinder with the heat generation and is surrounded by the air (with heat transfer coefficient), can we use the thermal resistance model in this scenario?

The issue is that the spatial dependence of the heat generation needs to be specified, and so the easiest answer to your question is no. Numerical methods can be used to discretize any general distribution to create an equivalent circuit approximation, but this will always be an approximate representation and solution.

@looksquirrel101, I, too, was thinking the same. But one question that I have is, "Can't I define thermal resistance from its first definition?" That is if I know the heat transfer and the associated temp diff, then I am done by taking their ratio. Do you think that this should work?

@Ankush, it's very common in practical problems to not know the temperature of the source, and therefore not know the temperature difference. For example, if I'm analyzing the heat produced by a circuit board I know that "chip U1" is producing 10 W of heat...but the whole point of my analysis is to find out if that's enough to heat the chip above 150 C or not --- the temperature is an unknown to be found and not a known parameter.

You can define the thermal resistance for steady state, but not for transient heat up of the element.  The thermal resistance would be based on the difference between the volume average temperature and the temperature at the surface.

@Ankush - I think that if you are not interested in the details of the temperature distribution where the source is active, then you could create a representative circuit with a current source and a resistor representing that region of material. Then you would have the temperatures for regions outside of the source, but not for the region with the source.
